# ListGrid Duplicates created after adding records onload then dragging the same again

Tags: smartgwt

I have a View where I have Drag and Drop working between 2 ListGrid-s, and after dragging a few records I then save them to a POJO type object upon clicking a button "Save".

When I'm accessing again that view it calls a method `loadGrid` that pulls those values from the POJO and adds them back into the `ListGrid` that they were dragged to earlier, so they can see what they already have added previously, however when I drag and drop again it lets me add the same primary keys creating duplicates records in the ListGrid.

How can I make it so that it sees these records as the same? The primary key is the same, the types are the same, not sure what it could be...

I'm using `transferSelectedData` to add the new privileges to the assigned list grid and `setPreventDuplicates(true)`.

```
ListGrid avPrivGrid = null;
 ListGrid assPriv = null;
 TransferImgButton but = null;

 avPrivGrid = new ListGrid();
 PrivilegesDataSource privDataSource = new PrivilegesDataSource();
 avPrivGrid.setDataSource(privDataSource);
 avPrivGrid.setAutoFetchData(false);

 ListGridField propUsername = new ListGridField("privName", "Available Priv");
 propUsername.setType(ListGridFieldType.TEXT);
 avPrivGrid.setFields(propUsername);

 assPriv = new ListGrid();
 assPriv.setCanAcceptDroppedRecords(true);
 assPriv.setCanEdit(false); 
 assPriv.setAutoFetchData(false);
 assPriv.setPreventDuplicates(true);
 assPriv.setDuplicateDragMessage("Can not add duplicates!");
 assPriv.setCanSelectAll(false);
 assPriv.setAlternateRecordStyles(true);
 assPriv.setLeaveScrollbarGap(true);
 assPriv.setMinHeight(100);

 ListGridField propUserN = new ListGridField("privName", "Assigned Priv");
 propUserN.setWidth("30%");
 propUserN.setType(ListGridFieldType.TEXT);
 ListGridField propId = new ListGridField("privId");
 propId.setWidth("30%");
 propId.setType(ListGridFieldType.TEXT);
 propId.setHidden(true);
 assPriv.setFields(propId, propUserN);

 but = new TransferImgButton(TransferImgButton.RIGHT);
  but.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
 {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        //Duplicate checking will happen automagially!
            assPriv.transferSelectedData(avPrivGrid);
    }
 });
 avPrivGrid.fetchData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the ID field set as the primary key in the Datasource.

```
[IdField].setPrimaryKey(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I have [IdField].setPrimaryKey(true);
Up to here, my conclusion is that **whenever there is a databound list of records, the setDragDataAction(DragDataAction.MOVE) is not working**. If it's not databound, it works.

Comment: i have your same problem!
Any suggestions..?